# Mocking Python iterables for use with Sphinx

Tags: python, mocking, python-sphinx, python-mock

I'm using Sphinx to document a project that depends on wxPython, using the **autodocs** extension so that it will automatically generate pages from our docstrings. The **autodocs** extension automatically operates on every module you `import`, which is fine for our packages but is a problem when we `import` a large external library like wxPython. Thus, instead of letting it generate everything from wxPython I'm using the `unittest.mock` [library module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock) (previously the external package [**Mock**](http://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)). The most basic setup works fine for most parts of wxPython, but I've run into a situation I can't see an easy way around (likely because of my relative unfamiliarity with **mock** until this week).

Currently, the end of my `conf.py` file has the following:

```
MOCK_MODULES = ['wx.lib.newevent']  # I've skipped irrelevant entries...

for module_name in MOCK_MODULES:
    sys.modules[module_name] = mock.Mock()
```

For all the wxPython modules but [`wx.lib.newevent`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.newevent.html#module-lib.newevent), this works perfectly. However, here I'm using the [`newevent.NewCommandEvent()`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.newevent.html#lib.newevent.NewCommandEvent) function[1] to create an event for a particular scenario. In this case, I get a warning on the `NewCommandEvent()` call with the note `TypeError: 'Mock' object is not iterable`.

While I can see how one would use [patching](http://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/patch.html) to handle this for building out unit tests (which I will be doing in the next month!), I'm having a hard time seeing how to integrate that at a simple level in my Sphinx configuration.

**Edit:** I've just tried using `MagicMock()` as well; this still produces an error at the same point, though it now produces `ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack`. That seems like a step in the right direction, but I'm still not sure how to handle this short of explicitly setting it up for this one module. Maybe that's the best solution, though?

---

#### Footnotes

1. Yes, that's a function, naming convention making it look like a class notwithstanding; wxPython follows the C++ naming conventions which are used throughout the wxWidgets toolkit.

Comment: In all my encounters with Sphinx, it ha never automatically documented something I didn't explicitly tell it to, so can you please elaborate a bit on which part of Sphinx is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Good. It's the `autodoc` module that's causing the issue: it automatically includes all modules referenced by `import` statement. I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error, it looks like it is actually executing `newevent.NewCommandEvent()`, so I assume that somewhere in your code you have a top-level line something like this:

```
import wx.lib.newevent
...
event, binder = wx.lib.newevent.NewCommandEvent()
```

When autodoc imports the module, it tries to run this line of code, but since `NewCommandEvent` is actually a `Mock` object, Python can't bind its output to the `(event, binder)` tuple.  There are two possible solutions.  The first is to change your code to that this is not executed on import, maybe by wrapping it inside `if __name__ == '__main__'`.  I would recommend this solution because creating objects like this on import can often have preblematic side effects.

The second solution is to tell the `Mock` object to return appropriate values thus:

```
wx.lib.newevent.NewCommandEvent = mock.Mock(return_value=(Mock(), Mock()))
```

However, if you are doing anything in your code with the returned values you might run into the same problem further down the line.

Comment: This makes sense. I'll give a whirl later and confirm that it resolves the issue for me—assuming it does, I'll accept the answer. Thanks!